# Data export to the excel

Tags: php, laravel

I have added the functionality to my code for exporting the data into the Excel sheet but I am getting old field name here is my code this is the updated code

```
Route::get('students/download/excel', function () {
    $students = Student::all();
    
    $spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
    $sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
    $sheet->setCellValue('A1', 'ID');
    $sheet->setCellValue('B1', 'Name');
    $sheet->setCellValue('C1', 'Email');
    $sheet->setCellValue('D1', 'Phone No.');
    $sheet->setCellValue('E1', 'Address');
    $sheet->setCellValue('F1', 'Course');
    $sheet->setCellValue('G1', 'Highest Qualification');
    
    foreach ($students as $index => $student) {
        $row = $index + 2;
        $sheet->setCellValue('A' . $row, $student->id);
        $sheet->setCellValue('B' . $row, $student->name);
        $sheet->setCellValue('C' . $row, $student->email);
        $sheet->setCellValue('D' . $row, $student->phone_number);
        $sheet->setCellValue('E' . $row, $student->address);
        $sheet->setCellValue('F' . $row, $student->select_course);
        $sheet->setCellValue('G' . $row, $student->highest_qualification);
    }

    $writer = new Xlsx($spreadsheet);
    $fileName = 'students.xlsx';
    $writer->save($fileName);
    return response()->download($fileName)->deleteFileAfterSend();
})->name('students.download.excel');
```

and this is my old field name in the excel

```
 $sheet->setCellValue('A1', 'ID');
    $sheet->setCellValue('B1', 'Name');
    $sheet->setCellValue('C1', 'Email');
    $sheet->setCellValue('D1', 'phone_number');
    $sheet->setCellValue('E1', 'address');
    $sheet->setCellValue('F1', 'select_course');
    $sheet->setCellValue('G1', 'highest_qualification');
```

but I am getting still old value names like phone_number, select_course when I try to export this in the excel.

Comment: Sounds like you either did not actually update the code as you think you did - or you are looking at an old result.

Comment: If u're sure not watching old file can try clear all caches